# jQuery timer without date

Tags: php, jquery, timer

I want to get the difference between two dates and then want to implement backward timer to show how much time left and timer should update after each second. I want to show aggregate hours between dates like 140:20:14. I am updating timer using setInterval function and subtracting seconds from time using `moment.js`. I am calculating total time left using following php code:

```
$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$hours = $difference->h + ($difference->days*24);
$minutes = $difference->i;

$seconds = $difference->s;

$difference =  "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
```

> But It works fine if hours are less then 24 otherwise it is showing wrong time.

PHP script return correct result but jQuery script returns wrong result after subtracting seconds

```
 var result_time = moment(result_time_left, 'hh:mm:ss').subtract('seconds', 1).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Here result time left is the result returned by PHP script.

I am unable to find its solution.

Please help.

Comment: You need to describe the exact problem. Does the php script return the wrong string? What do you expect and what do you get? And for what input values? And what does this have to do with javascript / jQuery / moment.js?

Comment: @jeroen pls see the edited question

Answer (score 0):

moment(result_time_left, 'hh:mm:ss') will interprete '140:20:14' as 14 hours, 20 minutes and 14 seconds. That is why you're not seeing the expected result.

If you can print both $datetime1 and $datetime2 to JS space, moment should be able to handle both dates and you can subtract them there instead

Comment: do u know any other way to deduct seconds from this format??

Comment: In PHP you can use 'sub' on the $difference datetime object directly: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom function to update timer because I couldn't get any other solution for this. Posting my answer here so that if anyone needs in future for the same then they can refer to this code. suggestions are welcome

function updateTimer(time)
{

```
split_time = update_time.split(':');

h = split_time[0]; m = split_time[1]; s = split_time[2];


if(s > 0)
{ 
    s = s-1;

}
else if(s == 0)
{
    s = 59;
    if(m != 0)
    {
        m = m-1;
    }
    else
    {
        m = 59;
        h = h - 1;
    }
}
else if(m == 0)
{
    s = s-1;
    m = 59;
    h = h-1
}


if(s <10)
{
    s = '0'+s;
}
if(m.length == 1 && m <10)
{

    m = '0'+m;
}

if(h < 10 && h.length == 1)
{
    h = '0'+$.trim(h);
}
if(m==0 && h==0 && s == 0)
{
    update_time = time;
}

update_time = h+ ':' + m + ':' + s;
return update_time;
```

}